# @font-face doesn't work in chrome, how can I fix that?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, font-face

I used font face to use custom font in Chrome, but it doesn't works.
In Firefox, it works well. How can I fix it?
This is what I wrote.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'abril';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
       url('./assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('./assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('./assets/fonts/AbrilFatface-Regular.svg') format('svg');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
}

div.page-title {
  font-family: 'abril';
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Vladmir, I think "eot" does work only on IE/Edge, I advise you to use "woff" instead & see this for more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: It also doesn't work well.

Comment: This font works well in firefox, but only in chrome and opera doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, kh3e, I solved this issue. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this font before. It worked well for me. Please try Using this [Google Font](http://%3Clink%20href=%22https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril%20Fatface%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%3E) (Hope its the same ). You can even download from there and use it.

[image]